# Chrome displaying as black window

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've got this issue, whenever I launch chrome it opens as it as this black box, not even the top bar is displayed as intended. This only happened when I changed my monitors, and one of the outputs on my GPU (from DVI + HDMI to DisplayPort + HDMI).

Any ideas why this is like this and how to fix this?

Here's a screenshot for reference.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps try the potential solutions at https://windowsreport.com/chrome-black-screen-problem-windows-10/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reinstalling your GPU-driver.
Id recommend using display driver unistaller, it´s supposed to bring the cleanest results.

If thats doesn`t work, reinstalling chrome could solve it aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to:

- Uninstall Chrome
- Scrub from the disk all folders whose name contains the string "chrome"
- Re-install Chrome

This should re-initialize all Chrome settings.